# When should I repot a pony tail palm?

Tags: houseplants

When should I repot a ponytail palm? Mine is quite large in what looks to me like a too small pot. It has been healthy but is now turning brown on lower tips and stopped growing.

Comment: you need to post a picture.

Comment: Interesting & good question about an important aspect of care for this type of palm, and a good detailed & informative answer can be seen following; This question about care for this type of palm is clearly stated; Although inclusion of illustrations & details about the specific one mentioned in the question could be helpful for suggestions regarding care for the specific one mentioned, the question itself is well stated, and the accompanying answer is useful & helpful for care of this type of palm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kay, typically you would repot it in the spring if it is touching the side of the pot. They will stay small if you keep them in the same pot for many year.  Eventually it might start to break the pot.  At that point you have to repot it.

You can repot every other year if you choose, but keep in mind this plant can get quite large.  Resizing the pot every other year is only going to encourage it to get larger.  The larger the pot you put it in the larger it will get.  The new pot should provide 1" between the trunk root and the side of the pot.

Even if you want to keep it small, it maybe time to change the soil.  Take the plant our of the pot, wash off all the soil.  Plant it back into the same pot with fresh soil.  This I would do every 2-3 year no matter what.  Plants need healthy soil.  Soil that has been in a pot for even a year, start to loose nutrients, as well as natural beneficial microbes in the soil. Soil is life.  A plant is only as healthy as the soil it is in.

To recap, repot it every 2 years, either back in the same pot or a new pot with 1" clearing on all sides in the spring time.

[Farmers Almanac on Ponytail Palms](https://www.almanac.com/plant/ponytail-palms#)

Comment: Good well written, detailed, and informative answer. Thank you